# Image with in select tag in html

Tags: html

Is it possible to place an image in a `<select>` dropdown list?

I tried the following piece of code

```
<select name="selection">
    <option><img src="dbdesign.jpg" alt="NOIMAGE"/>list1</option>
    <option><img src="dbdesign.jpg" alt="NOIMAGE"/>list2</option>
</select>
```

The output shows **list1** and **list2** but is not showing **NOIMAGE**, which is the alternative to src of image.

Comment: i think. you can't add an image in an option tag. Rather than you can simulate like a drop down using css and jquery

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697996/image-in-select-element

Answer (score 4):

You can't add an image to a select tag.

You can create custom menus using CSS/HTML/Javascript, but obviously this a lot more work.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help you a little. It should work. Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/jJfdr/4/

```css
#selection option {
    background: url('dbdesign.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
    padding-left: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    background-size: 50%;
}
```

```html
<select id="selection">
    <option>list1</option>
    <option>list2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Eventhough no change in page.!

Comment: @RAVITEJA  it should work. would you please take look at the link.

Comment: Is this CSS 3? What kind of browser support does this have?

Comment: @Jimmery Looks like there's nothing in here that was CSS3; you should bale to use this in IE6 if you wanted to.

Comment: @TylerH the CSS property background-image wasnt supported by IE until version 9 (http://caniuse.com/#search=background-image), the CSS seems fine, I was just wondering about the browser support for putting background images onto <option> tags