# How do I put an Image in a '<select>' s option value?

Tags: html, css, image, select, drop-down-menu

I am making a language selector and I want to add an image of the flag for the language but I cannot figure out how to do it. any thoughts or advice? I have used photoshop to resize my image to height=15px, currently though the image of the flag is not showing up. I want it set up so that when the user selects the menu, the flags will be on the most left hand side with a single space then the name of corresponding language.

```
<div class="ui-block-b"><select class="ui-selectmenu" name="selectmenu" id="destinationlang" align="center" width="40%">
      <option value="Destination Language">Destination Language</option>
      <option value="english" id="english">English</option>
      <option value="french" id="french"><img src="images/flags/frenchflagsmall.fw.png" alt="frenchflag" />French</option>
      <option value="spanish" id="spanish">Spanish</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: A dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image in SELECT element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697996/image-in-select-element)

Comment: that answer talks about putting the image as a background of the '<option>' I want the images to just be like an "inline" element with the string