# select box with images in Angular 5

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a select element in Angular 5 with bootstrap 3. I think it's a WebForms / Bootstrap component. Is it possible to attach images to the different options? Perhaps using CSS?

```
           <select (change)="course.active = !course.active"
                    name="myselect">
                <option [selected]="course.active" >
                    Option 1
                </option>
                <option [selected]="!course.active" >
                    Option 2
                </option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a duplicate question, you can find your answer there:

[Adding images with option tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562149/adding-images-with-option-tag) 
[How to add images in select list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list) 
[Image in SELECT element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697996/image-in-select-element)

You can't add image inside `<option>` the DOM doesn't allow it, `<option>` tag only accept plain text... so yes you need to add image using CSS and `style="background-image"` attribute to make it work.

I hope it help you :)